# sqlite python 3 insert OperationalError syntax

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, syntax, operationalerror

So I have a function that reads a txt, parses it, and loads it into a sql table.

```
 def main():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("myTable.db")
    crsr = connection.cursor()
    lines = open("LLA03132A.txt", "r").readlines()
    input = Thpt(lines)
    sql = """CREATE table if not exists my_table (
    date STRING,
    site STRING,
    sector STRING,
    avg_thpt FLOAT
    );"""
    crsr.execute(sql)
    for x in input:
        time = x[0]
        site = x[1][1:8]
        sector = x[1]
        avg_thpt = x[2]
        sql = """INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( %s , %s , %s , %f );"""%(time, site, sector, avg_thpt)
        print(sql)
        crsr.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

However, when I call it, I get this said error. What am I doing wrong? Am I mis-naming my categories or my values? Is there a hidden character somewhere? I am using the datetime package as well fyi

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( 2018-07-03 10:14:18.060416 , LA03132 , LLA03132A11 , 2637.806265 );
  File "C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/Parser/parser2.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/Parser/parser2.py", line 55, in main
    crsr.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "10": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using string interpolation, which is slow and unsafe, when you should use parameter passing instead.

Also `sqlite3.paramstyle` is **`'qmark'`**, so you should use `?` as placeholder for your parameters:

```
params = (x[0], x[1][1:8], x[1], x[2])
sql = """INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"""
print(sql)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

Note that the sql and the parameters are passed separately to the driver so it is the job of the database to do the parameter interpolation. This frees you from quote hell and makes your code safer by not allowing sql injection attacks. It is also faster.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're trying to insert `STRING` values into the database without appropriate quotation.  If you look at your `INSERT` statement that gets printed, it prints:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( 2018-07-03 10:14:18.060416 , LA03132 , LLA03132A11 , 2637.806265 );
```

What you want is for it to print:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( '2018-07-03 10:14:18.060416' , 'LA03132' , 'LLA03132A11' , 2637.806265 );
```

So you need to change this line of code:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( %s , %s , %s , %f );"""%(time, site, sector, avg_thpt)
```

to this:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , %f );"""%(time, site, sector, avg_thpt)
```